# How to generate a "add funds" button in sandbox?

Tags: php

I need to have a button that lets the user add funds to their account at our site via PP.  I can't see any of the buttons that allow me to dynamically specify the amount based on an input form element.

Any suggestions would be helpful.  Or is there another API that's better suited to this process?  I'm running a site programmed in php and have full control over the processes down to the bit level, if necessary :-)

Thanks, Jim

Comment: I've found non hosted buttons that appear to be on the right track, but I have yet to be able to specify an amount to be passed.  It would appear that adding and "amount" form element should work, but the following doesn't work

Comment: `<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
               <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <label>Name Your Price: <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="5.00"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----

Comment: I can't get it all in but there's nothing important following that chunk of code.  I added the id=... just in case, but it didn't work before I added it either.